# Where can I find lists that rank the difficulty of learning other languages based on your native language?

Tags: resource-request

I found a language learning difficulty study/grouping for native English speakers by the US Foreign Service Institute copied all over the web.

Do you know of something similar for native speakers of other languages. I am especially interested in such a list for Asians and Africans, since the list/grouping would be not much different for German or Spanish natives.

I do not need a resource for **every** language, I am just interested in such for **any** language.

That is, any 1 such list for a language other than English would be a great answer!

Comment: @fi12 I don't think it's unreasonable to wonder if there's a matrix somewhere where you can pick any language as see all the other languages relative to that one.

Comment: @fi12 I don't think a question is too broad just because the answer is "unlikely."

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that such a list or matrix is available. However, there may be a way around this for some languages. Many language schools in Europe state in their course descriptions which [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) level you are supposed to reach after the first, second, ... year of learning a specific language. (At least, that is what many language schools do in Flanders. I have also seen this type of information on UK websites.) Since these schools assume a specific native language, this kind of information should give you a rough estimate what the most difficult languages are when you start from a specific native language. Note that you need to get the hours of instructions, not simply the number of years, because some schools offer both "normal" and accelerated courses.

One word of warning: For Chinese, the CEFR levels will often be inaccurate. This appears to be a consequence of Hanban's publication of incorrect correspondence tables between [HSK levels and CEFR levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanyu_Shuiping_Kaoshi#Estimates_of_equivalent_CEFR_levels).